# Excluir linhas de tabela através de VBA

Tags: excel-vba

Estou com dificuldade em excluir as linhas de uma tabela, não só o conteúdo mas, que isso não afete as linhas da planilha.
Gravei uma macro que resultou no seguinte código:

```
Range("Tabela193").Select  
Selection.ListObject.ListRows(1).Delete  
Selection.ListObject.ListRows(1).Delete  
Selection.ListObject.ListRows(1).Delete
```

Isso funcionou mas como o número de linhas é variavel, tenho que colocar uma rotina que conte a quantidade de linhas e repita a linha "Selection.ListObject.ListRows(1).Delete" até a última linha.
Outro detalhe é que se tiver uma única linha e esta sem dados, ignore a rotina "Selection.ListObject.ListRows(1).Delete" e passe a selecionar outra tabela para copiar os dados da mesma.

Comment: Veja [esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/327517/75104)

Answer (score 1):

A pergunta foi um tanto quanto genérica, mas vamos ao caminho das pedras para você fazer suas adaptações.

Você não explicou se a intenção é excluir **todas** as linhas da tabela ou apenas algumas. Pelo texto da questão, parece que é para excluir todas, mas como seu código faz referência a uma range com um nome específico ("Tabela193"), vejamos os dois casos.

**Se você quiser excluir todas as linhas em uso na planilha,** é preciso referenciar todo o intervalo em uso numa planilha. Para isso, usamos a propriedade `UsedRange` da planilha -- depois é só iterar todas as linhas, excluindo-as. Por exemplo:

```
Sub eitcha()
    Dim lnCont As Long

    For lnCont = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
        ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows(lnCont).Delete
    Next lnCont
End Sub
```

Lembrando que `activesheet` pode ser substituída pela referência à planilha que deve ser apagada (por exemplo, no seu caso, `Range("Tabela193").worksheet`, que deve dar no mesmo que `activesheet`).

**Se você quiser excluir apenas as linhas daquela *range*,** basta uma pequena adaptação: em vez de excluir todas as linhas da `UsedRange`, excluiremos as linhas da Range("Tabela193").

```
Sub BatataDoce()
    Dim lnCont As Long

    For lnCont = Range("Tabela193").Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
        Range("Tabela193").Rows(lnCont).Delete
    Next lnCont
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

Desse jeito é mais prático

```
Planilha.ListObjects("Tabela193").DataBodyRange.Delete
```