# VBA - Apagar apenas última linha da tabela que contém um texto

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, planilha

Estou com uma dúvida um tanto quanto específica.
Espero que possam me ajudar

Possuo uma planilha que contem uma tabela chamada "Atividades". Tenho alguns controles de formulário para preencher a mesma mas me surgiu a necessidade de inserir e excluir linhas dessa tabela sem interferir nas células ao seu lado. Preencher uma nova linha da tabela sem afetar as células do lado não é problema, já consegui fazer isso. O problema está sendo excluir a linha da coluna que contenha o valor adicionado (apenas o último). Segue imagens para ilustrar o que pretendo fazer.

[image: imagem]

Ao clicar no botão + de "Telefonemas Atendidos", ele adiciona uma linha na tabela "Atividades" com o texto "Atendimento de Telefone".

Gostaria de poder fazer a mesma coisa com o botão menos, ao clicar nele, a última linha contendo "Atendimento de Telefone" seja excluída (apenas o último dentro da tabela), mas de forma a não interferir nas células com o retângulo em azul.

Será que tem como? Como podem ver, já possuo um controle que consegue apagar a última linha da tabela, uso esse código para fazer isso:

```
Private Sub RemoveLinha_Click()
Dim i As Integer
i = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Atividades").Range.Rows.Count
If i > 2 Then
    Range("D" & i).ListObject.ListRows(i - 1).Delete
End If
End Sub
```

No entanto, não sei como identificar apenas o último valor contendo o texto específico para cada botão de menos que eu adicionar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como o [ListObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/vba/excel-vba/articles/listobject-object-excel) está sendo utilizado, segue o código para deletar a última linha.

## Última linha da tabela com valor

Este é um código que cria uma matriz com os valores da tabela e realiza um loop reverso (da última linha até a primeira) na coluna 2 procurando o valor de "Telefonemas Atendidos" e se encontrar, remove a linha e sai do loop.

### Código

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim tbl As ListObject
Dim i As Long
Dim matriz As Variant
Set ws = ActiveSheet                         'ou para declarar com o nome da planilha: ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Agosto")
Set tbl = ws.ListObjects("Nome_da_Tabela")   'No seu caso: .ListObjects("Atividades")
With tbl
    matriz = .DataBodyRange                   'Cria matriz
    For i = UBound(matriz) To LBound(matriz) Step -1
        If matriz(i, 2) = "Telefonemas Atendidos" Then
            .ListRows(i).Delete
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
End With
```

## Última Linha

### Código

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim tbl As ListObject

Set ws = ActiveSheet                         'ou para declarar com o nome da planilha: ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Agosto")
Set tbl = ws.ListObjects("Nome_da_Tabela") 'No seu caso: .ListObjects("Atividades")
With tbl
    .ListRows(.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count).Delete
End With
```

### Explicação

- Com `Set ws = ActiveSheet` a planilha ativa é atribuída à variável `ws` ou `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Agosto")` pode ser utilizado para atribuir pelo nome da Planilha.
- Com `Set tbl = ws.ListObjects("Nome_da_Tabela")` a tabela é atribuída à variável `tbl`
- Com `tbl.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count` a última linha é encontrada
- Com `tbl.ListRows(Número da Linha).Delete` a linha de index `n` é removida

#### Problema na Declaração de i

Com `Dim i As Integer` você possuirá erros se a planilha crescer muito.

> **Observação:** Declarar como Long (`Dim i As Long`), pois muitos tutoriais antigos utilizam o Integer, que possui 2 bytes e
>   o intervalo de     –32 768 a 32 767. Portanto, se a versão do Excel for
>   maior do que 2007, o programa irá parar após a linha 32767. Já o Long
>   possui 4 bytes e intervalo de -2 147 483 648 a 2 147 486 647. Em que o
>   Excel possui um limite de 1 048 576 linhas.

Comment: Daniel, não existe pessoa mais iluminada que você!
Muito obrigado mesmo, de coração! Era exatamente isso que eu estava tentando fazer, acho que simplesmente não estava enxergando mais aonde eu estava errando! Eu quebrei a cabeça durante 2 semanas por causa disso haha! E não entendia por que minha lógica estava errada! Eu cheguei até a parte do loop, e encontrava os textos, mas o código apagavam todas as linhas que continham o texto, não apenas a ultima! Agora voce me ensinou como fazer e serei eternamente grato! 
Abraços!

Comment: Favor ler [Como e por que aceitar uma resposta?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/75104)